# Word meaning existing only in the present?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was watching a video I cannot find describing television before the VCR. And it used a word to describe the fact that television could not be rewound or paused. This word also applies to spoken language but not written language. It is an adjective and describes things that only exist in the present. They do not exist in the past or the future. They are also normally a continuous stream of information but I do not know if that is pertinent. I cannot remember this word and I was wondering if anyone knows of this word.

Comment: There's "transient" and its synonyms.

Comment: Are you thinking of ***ephemeral***?

Comment: Both good words. look them up in a thesaurus now.

Answer (score 2):

**ephemeral**
*But because of the **ephemeral** nature of television news in the 1940s , that rediscovery is not possible since those broadcasts could not be recorded.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Origins_of_Television_News_in_Americ/VKkQP6b6IDsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22But%20because%20of%20the%20ephemeral%20nature%20of%20television%20news%20in%20the%201940s%20%2C%20that%20rediscovery%20is%20not%20possible%22&pg=PA171&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22But%20because%20of%20the%20ephemeral%20nature%20of%20television%20news%20in%20the%201940s%20%2C%20that%20rediscovery%20is%20not%20possible%22)

**transient**
*The **transient** nature of television programming and the loss or inaccessibility of original program material make thorough analysis of specific programs, series, formats, and genres difficult.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fifties_Television/sWjhCESKy4AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22transient%20nature%20of%20television%22&pg=PA4&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22transient%20nature%20of%20television%22)

**transitory**
*…the instantaneous and **transitory** nature of radio in the days before recording capabilities were widespread…* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Feminine_Frequencies/3yH4yyVIYYIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22transitory%20nature%20of%20radio%22&pg=PA28&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22transitory%20nature%20of%20radio%22)

**impermanent**
*I joined WFMU & loved the transitory, **impermanent** nature of radio even more than I did the printed page.* [(source)](https://web.archive.org/web/20210113000101/http://bobrixon.blogspot.com/2012/09/john-cage-born-september-5-1912.html?m=1)

**fugacious**
*…how **fugacious** radio reporting is: a radio broadcast can be missed, not so a book.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Schutzian_Phenomenology_and_Hermeneutic/rb7EBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22how%20fugacious%20radio%20reporting%20is%22&pg=PA106&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22how%20fugacious%20radio%20reporting%20is%22)

**fleeting**
*Unfortunately because of the **fleeting** nature of radio news, it was impossible to review what had been said and what precisely had been its effect.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Geohazards/6NkoBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22fleeting%20nature%20of%20radio%22&pg=PA48&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22fleeting%20nature%20of%20radio%22)

**flitting**
*They are happy in their earthly gladness, satisfied with their human ambitions, unaware meanwhile of the **flitting** nature of this world and of the eternal stability of the spiritual world.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Record_of_Christian_Work/IHXS3q6x-lYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22flitting%20nature%20of%22&pg=PA509&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22flitting%20nature%22)

**passing**
*And then, we are reminded of the fragile and **passing** nature of human life and we recall that we must always be ready to greet Christ our Lord.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sunday_Prayer_for_Catechists_2011_2012/c4DTSiyT2QUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22passing%20nature%20of%22&pg=PA16&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22passing%20nature%20of%22)

**unenduring**
*There is no greater delusion than to impress on people the **unenduring** nature of earthly things that on earth we live up to a certain period of time…* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/County_society/6cIBAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22unenduring%20nature%20of%22&pg=PA230&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22unenduring%20nature%20of%22)

**evanescent**
*Because of the **evanescent** nature of radio, action and events unfold in the moment; there is no 'rewind' function or visual staging prior to sound.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=941&tbs=bkv%3Ap&tbm=bks&ei=G0H-X7ynDuHV5gL9m6WACA&q=%22evanescent+nature+of+radio%22&oq=%22evanescent+nature+of+radio%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299k1l2.129398.131906.0.132192.7.7.0.0.0.0.101.550.6j1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.298....0.hZ8xhdV3mZg)

**volatile** (in the sense of 'difficult to capture or hold permanently : evanescent, transitory'; see [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/volatile))
**short-lived**
*the **volatile**, **short-lived** nature of radio broadcasts* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Media_in_Latin_America/EdlEBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22%20short-lived%20nature%20of%20radio%22&pg=PA124&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22%20short-lived%20nature%20of%20radio%22)

**fugitive** (in the sense of 'being of short duration'; see [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fugitive))
*We regularly hear laments about the **fugitive** nature of television product and the fact that we lack sufficient archival material to enable detailed histories of Australian television to be written.* [(source)](https://www.semanticscholar.org/author/N.-King/39142099?sort=influence&page=2)

Comment: It’s a broadcast or, as a verb, broadcasting. From AHD, “1. To communicate or transmit (a signal, a message, or content, such as audio or video programming) to numerous recipients simultaneously over a communication network: a radio station that broadcasts news; an agency broadcasting an appeal for donations over the internet.“

Answer (score 0):

What you describe makes me think of ***live broadcasting***. It shows events happening ***simultaneously*** ("as they happen") and it could be described as ***a real-time transmission***. In this sense, the adjective "live" can describe what you call "a continuous stream of information".

However, it does not meet your instruction:

> This word also applies to spoken language but not written language

***on-air*** is also an option you might want to consider:

> broadcast while actually happening ([Idoceonline](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/on-air))
>
> Ex: Pahdra Singh handled his on-air interview brilliantly, and pointed out to Labone that grandstands are not insured against theft.